# Transform boundary conditions to homogeneous conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> We have
>
> $$ \begin{cases} u_t = k u_{xx}, x \in (0,l), t > 0 \\ u(0,t) =
>  g_1(t), \\ u(l,t) = g_2(t), t > 0 \\ u(x,0) = u_0(x), x \in [0,l]
>  \end{cases} $$
>
> Show boundary conditions can be transformed into homogeneous boundary
>   conditions.

### try

The idea is to introduce some $w(x,t)$ so that $w(0,t)=w(l,t)=0$. We want to have

$$ w(x,t) = u(x,t) - something $$

Actually, we can check that

$$ w(x,t) = u(l-x,t) - \frac{ (g_1(t)-g_2(t)) }{l}(x-l) - g_1(t) $$

Note that $w(0,t) = g_2 + (g_2-g_1)(-1) - g_1 = 0 $ and $w(l,t) = g_1 - g_1 = 0$ so this the condition we want. However, in my solution it says. Take

$$ w(x,t) = u(x,t) - \frac{ (g_1(t)-g_2(t)) }{l}(x-l) - g_1(t) $$

This is wrong since it doesnt give homogeneous bc. Am I wrong or the answer key is wrong?

Comment: The answer key should swap $g_1$ and $g_2$

Comment: my answer is correct as well

Comment: Yes. They can't both be correct. Yours is, the answer key isn't.